# Simple job scheduler in script language for Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, scripting, job-scheduling

I have defined set of tests, each test can run from 1 sec till 10 minutes. I want to run them after each code submit. Now it takes too long to run them sequentially.

Is there any ready-to-use scheduler, which can help me to run those jobs in parallel with the pre-defined level of parallelization?

Input:

- List of programms to call with arguments.
- Number of job to run in parallel.

Output:

- List of jobs together with their return code (0 ok, -1 error)
- General status (ok or failed - if at least one job failed).
- Run duration for each job (optional)

Does this exists as ready-to-use implementation in the script language (bash, perl, python)? Target environment is Linux. All runs on the same host, job distribution is not needed. The most simple solution is the best. Since I am not an expert in the scripting languages, I would prefer a ready solution (working script), instead of the link to the library, which can be used to implement the solution.

I did research, but I didn't find any ready solution. My intuition it is general task, which must be solved already.

Comment: [`parallel`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) gets you part of the way there. Maybe it's good enough?

Comment: Looks very promising, @Thomas, thank you! How could I overlook a standard command!

Comment: It's not installed by default, and not very well-known. I only learned of it recently myself :)

Answer (score 0):

[Sparky](https://github.com/melezhik/sparky) is able to run jobs on remote hosts or localhost asynchronously. Mostly what you need.

Ps. Disclosure, I am the tool author.